# Filter an array of dictionaries and change its attributes

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter

I have an array of dictionaries `var songsByLetters = [(key: String, value: [Song])]()` and the user has selected a song and he will put it in his favorites. So i will need to change the selected song `id` `isFaved` boolean to `true`.

Before i had and array of song object without the first letters of the song as keys to the new dictionary. And i used to do this when user tapped fav button.

```
@IBAction func favButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   dbSongs.filter({$0.id == selectedSongId}).first?.isFaved = sender.isSelected
}
```

Now as i have a dictionaries I'm trying to do this but its not just the correct way and i have an error of course.

> Cannot convert value of type '()?' to closure result type 'Bool'

```
songsByLetters.filter{$0.value.filter{$0.id == selectedSongId}.first?.isFaved = sender.isSelected}
```

I understand the error but i don't know how to filter this dictionary and change the `isFaved` attribute of that certain song `id`

Here is the song structure:

```
[
"H":[
       {
         "id": 2134,
         "name": "Happy Brithday",
         "artist": "Paul Anka",
         "isFaved": false,
         "code": "380dj0a"
       },
       {
         "id": 38304,
         "name": "How can i stop loving you",
         "artist": "Savage Garden",
         "isFaved": false,
         "code": "kkdj0a"
       }
   ]
]
```

Comment: Please put the sample dictionary also

Comment: First filter the song array by song name (letter), then by `id`.

Comment: @vadian this means i need to know the key letter also not only the faved song id to filter this.

Comment: Yes, this increases the efficiency of the filter operation considerably.

Comment: Can you please attach the structure of dbSongs

Comment: @mouseymaniac here you go

Comment: @Rizwan here you go

Comment: Where do you get `selectedSongId` from?

Comment: @vadian when user taps on the song row in `didSelectRow` and save it in a global variable `self.selectedSongId = songsByLetters[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].id`

Comment: That mean that you easily could save the letter as well, `songsByLetters[indexPath.section]`, and simplify the filtering or do it directly in `didSelectRow` perhaps

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thats true this is what i’m trying to do now

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than keeping only the `id` keep the entire `Song`.

```
var selectedSong : Song?

...

self.selectedSong = songsByLetters[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row]
```

The most efficient solution is to declare `Song` as class with reference semantics then  you don't need to filter at all

```
@IBAction func favButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    selectedSong?.isFaved = sender.isSelected
}
```

Note: You are discouraged from using a tuple (your *dictionary* is actually a tuple) as data source.

Comment: Yes it is an `NSManagedClass` CoreData but the ideas is that the data that i get from the api itself and save it in CoreData is not keyed i'm adding the keys in a new dictionary like this   `songsByLetters = Dictionary(grouping: dbSongs, by: { String($0.name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).first!)}).sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0}) ` to have first letter index in my `UITableView` same as the iOS contacts so now when changing the `isFaved` will not persist i will need to edit the songsByLetters value `isFaved` attribute directly.

Comment: If `Song` is a class the value will be changed also in the array as `selectedSong` and the item in the dictionary point to the same object. And from performance perspective your array of **tuples** is not very efficient. Keep the original **grouped dictionary** and create an array `var keys = dictionary.keys.sorted()`. Use keys as section and get the rows by key. That's a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

//First you can filter the object

```
let filtered = dbSongs.filter({$0.id == selectedSongId}).first
```

//then remove from list

```
let index = dbSongs.index { $0.id == filtered.id }

  if let index = index {
        let removed = dbSongs.remove(at: index) // Remove item
  }
```

//Update details

```
removed.isFaved = true
```

//finally insert to list.

```
dbSongs.insert(removed, at index)
```

Comment: Im trying to do it to the `songsByLetters` dictionary not the `dbSongs` array the `dbSongs` i have already did it. But now i changed my array to a dictionary of `var songsByLetters = [(key: String, value: [Song])]()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following code works

```
  struct Song {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
        let artist: String
        var isFaved: Bool
        let code: String
    }

    var songsByLetter: [String: [Song]] = ["H" : [Song(id: 2134, name: "Happy Birthday", artist: "Paul Anka", isFaved: false, code: "380dj0a"),Song(id: 38304, name: "How can i stop loving you", artist: "Savage Garden", isFaved: false, code: "kkdj0a")]]



    let selectedSongId = 38304
    var songs = songsByLetter.values.map({$0.filter({$0.id == selectedSongId})})

    if let songByH = songs.first, var song = songByH.first
    {
        song.isFaved = true
        let firstLetter = String(song.name.first ?? "0")
        let index = songsByLetter[firstLetter]?.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == selectedSongId})
        if let index = index
        {
            (songsByLetter[firstLetter])?.remove(at: index)
            songsByLetter[firstLetter]?.insert(song, at: index)
        }
    }

    print(songsByLetter)
```